# How to split a number into an array of its digits (in Ruby)?

Tags: ruby

**How to split a number into an array of its digits?**

`123` should become `[1,2,3]`

I found this [thread](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/217041) in the Ruby forum when I was looking for an idiomatic solution to the question above. The solutions there are working for me and they seem fine, I am using `.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i)`

But the thread is quite old, and I want to known if there are better, maybe newer ways to solve the task, given that Ruby as a language has developed further?

**Known solutions:**

`.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i)`

`12345.to_s.scan(/./)`

How do you solve it? Why?
To me as a beginner, seeing different ways to solve a problem helps a lot to 
understand the language and its use better. So, thanks for your input!

Comment: What's wrong with `chars.map(&:to_i)`? It works. If you're using that frequently enough it's an irritation make a method that does it for you.

Comment: As I said, nothing wrong with it. On the contrary, I like it. I am just wondering if there are more ways.

Comment: That's a pretty minimal approach, but if you want you can extend Integer to have a method called `digits` that does this.

Comment: Well the numbers are in denary so you could deconstruct them with this in mind.

Comment: We don't need a second question for the "best" answer, and your titles shouldn't include "best" in them. The "best" is implied by asking the question; obviously you're interested in the *best* answer or we wouldn't have a system where voting causes the higher-voted answers to bubble upwards.